# I'm trying to simplify the code to a nested loop

Tags: javascript, loops

I'm learning js and I just made a password generating code, the problem is I'm trying to simplify the code using loops inside loops, Can anyone help me understand how to do it.

```js
function genPassword() {
  let chars = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz!@#$%^&*()ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
  var passwordLength = 12;
  var password1 = "";
  var password2 = "";
  var password3 = "";
  var password4 = "";
  for (var i = 0; i <= passwordLength; i++) {
    var randomNumber1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length);
    var randomNumber2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length);
    var randomNumber3 = Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length);
    var randomNumber4 = Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length);
    password1 += chars.substring(randomNumber1, randomNumber1 + 1);
    password2 += chars.substring(randomNumber2, randomNumber2 + 1);
    password3 += chars.substring(randomNumber3, randomNumber3 + 1);
    password4 += chars.substring(randomNumber4, randomNumber4 + 1);
  }
  document.getElementById("password-1").textContent = password1;
  document.getElementById("password-2").textContent = password2;
  document.getElementById("password-3").textContent = password3;
  document.getElementById("password-4").textContent = password4;
}

genPassword()
```

```html
<div id="password-1"></div>
<div id="password-2"></div>
<div id="password-3"></div>
<div id="password-4"></div>
```

Comment: Where are you wanting to nest your loops? What have you attempted to nest them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's consider how you might do this without explicit loops.

You can generate an array of arbitratry length (`len`) as follows:

```
[...new Array(len)]
```

You can then map the items in this array with `Array.prototype.map`. We don't actually care about the default values in the array, so we can just discard that value and map it to a random character. It isn't necessary to use `substring`... a string can be indexed like an array (i.e. `chars[n]`)... so...

```
[...new Array(len)].map(() => chars[Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length)])
```

will give you back an array where each index contains a randomly selected character.

So now, all we have to do is join them back up again to form a string. `Array.prototype.join` does this for us:

```
[...new Array(len)]
    .map(() => chars[Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length)])
    .join("")
```

Let's pop all of this into a function:

```
function generatePassword(length){
  return [...new Array(len)]
      .map(() => chars[Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length)])
      .join("")
}
```

Calling `generatePassword(12)` will hand back a 12 char password.

Now, let's generate 4 of them using the same trick as above

```
const passwords = [...new Array(4)].map(() => generatePassword(passwordLength))
```

then let's output them:

```
passwords.forEach((password, index) => {
    document.getElementById("password-" + (index + 1)).textContent = password;
})
```

Putting it all together:

```js
const chars = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" + 
              "!@#$%^&*()ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
const passwordLength = 12;

function generatePassword(length) {
  return [...new Array(length)]
    .map(() => chars[Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length)])
    .join("");
}

const passwords = [...new Array(4)].map(() => generatePassword(passwordLength));

passwords.forEach((password, index) => {
  document.getElementById("password-" + (index + 1)).textContent = password;
})
```

```html
<div id="password-1"></div>
<div id="password-2"></div>
<div id="password-3"></div>
<div id="password-4"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just wrap the code for creating and displaying the password in another for loop. Make sure to change the number of iterations to match your project.

```js
function genPassword() {
    let chars = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz!@#$%^&*()ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    let passwordLength = 12;
    
    for (let j = 1; j <= 4; j++) {
        
        let password = "";
        for (let i = 0; i <= passwordLength; i++) {
            let randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length);
            password += chars.substring(randomNumber, randomNumber + 1);
        }
        document.getElementById("password-" + j).textContent = password;
    }
}
```

```html
<span id="password-1"></span><br />
<span id="password-2"></span><br />
<span id="password-3"></span><br />
<span id="password-4"></span><br />

<button onclick="genPassword()">Click</button>
```

Comment: Your answer was identical to mine, so I just upvoted yours and deleted mine.  Good job.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function genPassword() {
  let chars = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz!@#$%^&*()ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

let passwordArray = [
     { elemIdName: 'password-1', elemIdValue: ''},
     { elemIdName: 'password-2', elemIdValue: ''},
     { elemIdName: 'password-3', elemIdValue: ''},
     { elemIdName: 'password-4', elemIdValue: ''},
  ]
  let passwordLength = 12;

  for (var i = 0; i <= passwordLength; i++) {
    passwordArray.forEach((password) => {
      let randomNumber1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length);
      password.elemIdValue += chars.substring(randomNumber1, randomNumber1 + 1);
    })
  }
  passwordArray.forEach((password) => {
     document.getElementById(password.elemIdName).textContent = password.elemIdValue;
  })
}

genPassword()
```

```html
<div id="password-1"></div>
<div id="password-2"></div>
<div id="password-3"></div>
<div id="password-4"></div>
```